# How do I find the SDK version of an iPhone app

Tags: ios, xcode

We need to validate that our iOS apps are updated to SDK 11. For similar tasks on android we found some tools (e.g. system Info for Android) which shows the Android platform build version, but we did not find any similar apps for iOS. Is there any tool in App Store that we can use to validate the SDK build for our apps? Also is there any way in Xcode to find this piece of info?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. If you want to build with a Base SDK of iOS 11, use Xcode 9 and ensure you set the Base SDK to "latest".

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually the apps are already built by developers using SDK 10 or earlier. Now they are updating the apps to SDK 11 and our team needs to validate that the apps are updated to SDK 11 before release.

Comment: Read my original comment. If you do what I stated, they will be built with the iOS 11 SDK.